# How to exports many mongoose models modules in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, module

I have 2 models like this

```
const Db = mongoose.model('db', dbSchema); 
const Beacon = mongoose.model('beacon', dbSchema2);
```

Now I want to export them. First I export Db and everything is fine. I can do an HTTP request with it.

```
module.exports = Db;
```

However, when I try to export ´the 2nd one outside, it stops functioning. The functions below will return a blank JSON file as a response.

```
module.exports = Db;
module.exports = Beacon;
```

This won't work either. It returns an error handler saying all my functions in the handler is not function.

```
module.exports = {
Db, Beacon
}
```

This is the function on the file I import the models.

```
router.get('/data/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    Db.findOne({ _id: req.params.id }).then(function(db) { 
        res.send(db);
    });
}
```

The return from the handler is *Db.findOne is not a function.*

Is there any way to export them both? Thank you.
Here is the importing on another file

```
const Db = require('./db.js');
const Beacon = require('.db.js');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

*Exporting* in one file

```
module.exports = { Db, Beacon };
```

Then, *importing* in another file

```
const { Db, Beacon } = require('path-to-db.js');

// use them
Db.doSomething(); 
Beacon.doSomethingElse();
```

Notice that this uses the [ECMAS 6 Destructuring Assignment](http://es6-features.org/#ObjectMatchingShorthandNotation) (additional info on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment))